# Access the replied/forwarded/etc state from REST

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get and set the forwarded/replied state of an email message in the Graph API. This is the represented in OWA by the little icon in the right column.

It seems there is not a first class way to access this information, at least it does not come out in the unfiltered JSON dump.

Google suggests this is stored in the extended properties for PidTagLastVerbExecuted or PidTagIconIndex, however attempts to access these just give back 404:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/{id}/messages?$select=SingleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3Did+eq+'String+0x1081')
```

Other extended properties like 0x0070 do work, so it seems the syntax is correct, and 0x1081 comes from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaglastverbexecuted-canonical-property

This information is stored, you can see it in OWA, the Outlook apps, and you can see it in IMAP.

Is there some way to do this? It seems strange this basic information about the email state is not made available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specifying the wrong datatype that property is defined as a Long in the documentation (but the doco is for MAPI) so its actually an Integer in EWS and Graph eg this is something i used to return both PidTagLastVerbExecuted  and PidTagLastVerbExecutedTime (which gives you the time of the last action)for a particular message

```
/v1.0/users('user@domaincom')/MailFolders/AllItems/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,inferenceClassification,InternetMessageId,parentFolderId,hasAttachments,webLink,InternetMessageHeaders&$Top=1000&$filter=internetMessageId+eq+%27%3cSG2PR04MB3223962312D5B46D0C9CA1B5C89C0%40SG2PR04MB3223.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com%3e%27&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'Integer%200x1081')%20or%20(Id%20eq%20'SystemTime%200x1082'))
```

Comment: Yep, simple fix, now it works. The docs for this are really too short, they say there are only three valid ID forms for the filter (two with GUID), Integer and SystemTime are not listed options. This is working great now, but I'd also like to set the PidTagMessageStatus MSGSTATUS_ANSWERED bit for IMAP compatibility - any hope on that front? Thanks